# Is there a way to use a Dropdown widget to update plot SETTINGS on Bokeh?

Tags: plot, widget, bokeh

does anybody know a way to use a dropdown menu in bokeh to change settings from the plot? I don't really want to change the data, which is what I have usually seen. I want to make the scale of an axis to become logarithmic.

This is the relevant bits of what I have so far:

```
p3 = figure(y_axis_label='The scale is {}'.format(selected_scale), y_axis_type=selected_scale)

p3.line( x='date', y='value', source = src, legend_label='a label',muted_color=color[k], muted_alpha=0.1, alpha=.9)

def button_callback():
    sys.exit()  # Stop the server
# Button to stop the server
exit_button = Button(label="Stop", button_type="warning", background='red', width=50)
exit_button.on_click(button_callback)
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------


# Scale change
def change_scale(attr, old, new):
    selected_scale = seleccion.value
    p3 = figure(y_axis_label='The scale is {}'.format(selected_scale), y_axis_type=selected_scale)

    print(seleccion.value, new, 'Hello!!!')

selec = Select(title='Scale', options=['log', 'linear'], value='log', width=50)
selec.on_change('value', change_scale)

layout3 = gridplot([[selec], [p3], [exit_button]])

curdoc().add_root(layout3)
```

And then from Jupyter notebook I run

`!bokeh serve --show .\COVID19Bokeh.ipynb --port 5001`

which does open a new tab on my browser with the correct plot but it does not change the settings of `p3` as I would expect it to do.

Actually, after I go back to the jupyter notebook (after closing the tab) I do get the all prints coming from the `print(seleccion.value, new, 'Hello!!!')` statement but there is no change...

Answer (score 0):

By using `p3 = figure(...)` in your callback without actually using `p3` you're just creating a completely new plot and then throwing it away without using.

In Bokeh, if you want something changed, you should generally change the model directly. Sometimes, replace a child model of a parent model.

With that being said, axis type change in particular is not a very well supported thing, so you may experience some issues that require much more code than you'd expect. Some relevant links with discussions:

- https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6575
- https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5316
- https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/dynamic-change-scale-from-linear-to-log/5100

An idea that I've never tested - you can try to create two axes and switch between them by changing their `visible` attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. However, I have now dropped the Dropdown menu idea for a log scale interaction. It just seems too cumbersome.